# If you have multiple domains pointing to the same IP address, can you see which domain a packet was sent to?

Tags: dns

If you have multiple domains pointing to the same IP address, can you see which domain a packet was sent to?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Application-layer protocols such as HTTP generally have this capability.

At the network layer, no, you can't tell.

Comment: Note that the server name reported at the application layer is not necessarily the one actually used to resolve the server's IP address. For example, both `curl --resolve` and `openssl s_client -servername` can be used to "fake" the server name at the application layer.

Answer (score -1):

When multiple domains are mapped with same public address . While accessing any domain name this public ip will resolved    we can check this in online website like .

1. MX Toolbox .
2. DNS checker .